# Turning a regex returned as a string from an API into a valid RegEx object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, ecmascript-6

I'm fetching a regular expression from an external API, and it comes back as a string. I want to use the regex for address validation, but I can't seem to properly escape the unwanted characters after calling `new RegExp()` on the string.

Here's the regex I want to use:

`console.log(regexFromAPI);`

> Output

`/((\W|^)box\s+(#\s*)?\d+|post\s+office|(\W|^)p\.?\s*o\.?\s+(#\s*)?\d+)/i`

However, I can't use that -- I need it to actually be a regex first.

If I do, for example:

`const pattern = new RegExp(regexFromAPI);`

and then:

`console.log(pattern);`

I get the following:

> Output

`//((W|^)boxs+(#s*)?d+|posts+office|(W|^)p.?s*o.?s+(#s*)?d+)/i/`

My question is... why is this happening, and how can I avoid it? I want to use my string literal as a regex.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RegExp` constructor does not expect a string with `/` delimiters, nor with options past the final `/`. If you do that, the pattern generated from calling `new RegExp` with it will result in one that matches a string which starts with a literal forward slash `/`, and ends with a forward slash `/` followed by the flag characters (here, `i`).

Instead, you should pass the pattern string *without* `/` delimiters, and pass the flags as the second argument - you can extract these easily by using *another* regular expression:

```js
const fullPatternStr = String.raw`/((\W|^)box\s+(#\s*)?\d+|post\s+office|(\W|^)p\.?\s*o\.?\s+(#\s*)?\d+)/i`;

const [, pattern, flags] = fullPatternStr.match(/\/(.*)\/([a-z]*)/);
const regex = new RegExp(pattern, flags);
console.log(regex);
```

Comment: In that second line, can you explain why the `,` is necessary? I like this solution and it works, but I'm curious as to what that's doing.

Comment: `.match` returns an array, for which the first item will be the *full match* - which, in this case, will be the entire string, which you don't care about, so `[,` discards it (no variable name is between the `[` and the `,`), and only defines variables (through destructuring) for the second and third items in the array.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you for your insight (and for being willing to explain things!).

Answer (score 2):

Take off the slashes and flags, then reconstruct it:

```js
const str = String.raw`/((\W|^)box\s+(#\s*)?\d+|post\s+office|(\W|^)p\.?\s*o\.?\s+(#\s*)?\d+)/i`;
let regexBody = str.slice(1, str.lastIndexOf("/"));
let flags = str.split("/")[str.split("/").length - 1];
let regex = new RegExp(regexBody, flags);
console.log(regex);
```

Comment: `.split("/")` will result in errors if the pattern contains `/`s

Comment: You should also probably use `String.raw` to define the `str` identically to OP's, else you'll lose the escaped characters (just for the demo to be accurate)

Comment: My bad - I didn't know about that.